# Android selecting element from navigation bar freezes load

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-fragments, android-progressbar

I have a bottom navigation bar with multiple elements that send me to different fragments .

```
 bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.navigation_pokemon_description:
                            selectedFragment = PokemonDescriptionFragment.newInstance(MainActivity.getSelectedPokemon().get_id());
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_pokemon_evolutions:
                            selectedFragment = PokemonEvolutionsFragment.newInstance();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_pokemon_moves:
                            selectedFragment = PokemonMovesFragment.newInstance();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_pokemon_breeding:
                            selectedFragment = PokemonBreedingTrainingFragment.newInstance();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_pokemon_location:
                            selectedFragment = PokemonLocationFragment.newInstance();
                            break;
                    }
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

All the fragments works fine except the Moves fragment , when I press it , it costs around 3 seconds to load the data and display the fragment .

I would like to show the fragment first and then , load the moves and show a progress bar or something like that while the data is loading .

This is my fragment :

```
public class PokemonMovesFragment extends Fragment {


   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getContext());
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pokemon_moves, container, false);
    this.view=view;
    initalizeAllComponents();
    initializePokemonData();
    initializePostDataPopulationComponents();
    getActivity().setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.moves)+ " (" +selectedPokemon.getName() + ")");
    return view;
}
//The rest of the methods
```

Comment: Move your logic inside `onViewCreated(...)` this might help. In addition load data in background and bind to UI once it available

Comment: Worked like a charm , thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move all your logic inside `onViewCreated`, then show Progressbar before the logic and hide Progressbar after the logic

```
@Override
public View onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE; // Show Progress bar here
        initalizeAllComponents();
        initializePokemonData();
        initializePostDataPopulationComponents();
        getActivity().setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.moves)+ " (" +selectedPokemon.getName() + ")");
        progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE; // Hide Progress bar here
}
```